# Android upload to GoogleDrive: method header2(String) is undefined for the type View

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am trying to implement Resumable Media Uploading activity to GoogleDrive using Resumable Media Uploads .. so far the only error I get before compiling is :

> > The method header2(String) is undefined for the type View

in my  FileUploadProgressListener class.. should I implement a specific layout or use my current activity layout adding this view  ? could not get any info on it ...

```
import android.view.View;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener;
 import java.io.IOException;

 public class FileUploadProgressListener implements MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener {

  @Override
  public void progressChanged(MediaHttpUploader uploader) throws IOException {
    switch (uploader.getUploadState()) {
      case INITIATION_STARTED:
        View.header2("Upload Initiation has started.");
        break;
      case INITIATION_COMPLETE:
        View.header2("Upload Initiation is Complete.");
        break;
      case MEDIA_IN_PROGRESS:
        View.header2("Upload is In Progress: " + uploader.getProgress());
        break;
      case MEDIA_COMPLETE:
        View.header2("Upload is Complete!");
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

so far my uploading method is as following, hope I respected the google-api-java-client sample standard...

```
   .... static variables previously defined 
   mDirectoryPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/swimmer/swimlogs/";
   java.io.File file = new java.io.File(mDirectoryPath + java.io.File.separator + mFileName);
   mFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
  .....


      private static File uploadFile(boolean useDirectUpload) throws IOException {
        java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(mFileUri.getPath());

        Model.File fileMetadata = new File();
        fileMetadata.setParents(Arrays.asList(new ParentReference().setId(mFolderId)));
        fileMetadata.setTitle(fileContent.getName());
        InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent("text/csv", new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileContent)));
        mediaContent.setLength(fileContent.length());

        Drive.Files.Insert insert = mService.files().insert(fileMetadata, mediaContent);
        MediaHttpUploader uploader = insert.getMediaHttpUploader();
        uploader.setDirectUploadEnabled(useDirectUpload);  // set to false
        uploader.setChunkSize(MediaHttpUploader.MINIMUM_CHUNK_SIZE);
        uploader.setProgressListener(new FileUploadProgressListener());
        return insert.execute();
  }
```

Comment: I changed the View.header2(String) to a simple Log .. but I get an IOException.... after displaying "Initiation has started!"  it seems that the "Initiation is complete! don't pass...  fif I miss any important parameter ?   I put a e.printStackTrace(); statement but I cannot see the trace ad what happen....

Comment: I finally moved to DialogProgress pattern using Handler ... it works fine

Comment: how you are intializing mService